# How to define new component origin in EagleCad board view

Tags: pcb, design, eaglecad, cad

I have been trying to rotate a component in my eagle pcb board mode but the centre of rotation has been defined upon one of the pins of said part. (potentiometer)

This is what I have done so far: I edit the component package and moved the whole part so that the centre is located in the middle of the part and save.

When I try and change package whilst in board view, the new origin has not changed and the part rotates about one of the pins instead of its central origin where I would prefer.

How is it possible to redefine the central origin of this component in board view please?

Comment: Did you run "Library->Update...->(select library file)" or "Library->Update All" from the layout editor menu after editing the library?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I ran update library after editing.

Comment: The new origin has not been redefined. Is this helpful at all please? I can open package and see the origin of the part has been set. I cannot however, open device. I get this error: Package variant 'ALPHATHONK' of deviceset DUAL does not exist in current library C:/Users/Icarus.DESKTOP-AUNTROP/Downloads/303parts.lbr.
Please adjust the library paths or export the drawing libraries first!

Comment: Change of plan...sever f/b annotation and replace part. Ensure pins are labelled the same as the part being replaced. Solved thank you for the help so far.